# Language picker drop down list as html helper or partial + implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I'm new with MVC 3, so at this time I'm trying to create a website where I have a language picker and i can change the language on the website.

I have a JQuery + html for language picker.

But now I would like to know how to integrate it with MVC 3?

Here is the html for it:

```
<div id="polyglotLanguageSwitcher">
    <form action="#">
        <select id="polyglot-language-options">
            <option id="en" value="en" selected>English</option>
            <option id="fr" value="fr">Français</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is in partial template and it is used in the _Layout page

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#polyglotLanguageSwitcher').polyglotLanguageSwitcher({
                effect: 'fade',
                testMode: true,
                onChange: function (evt) {
                    alert("The selected language is: " + evt.selectedItem);
                }
```

Now if i want it to make working i can call with javascript to the server code and let the language change for the website, but then i will have to implement it in every controller this method to call right?

How can i do it in general? So that i can define this method only somewhere once and this can be called all the time, instead of writing or calling it on different controllers?

I was thinking of making this _partial template as a html.helper, is this a good descision? And if so how could i make it?

Thanks

To change the language basically i use the route path (/lang/action/id) and the cookie to store user selected language.

Comment: The first thing you should decide is how do you intend to store/pass the selected language on each request. Have you made that architectural decision yet? Ar you going to use a route parameter, cookie or a server side session variable? How do you intend to set the current thread CultureInfo on each request?

Comment: Yes, i'm using route parameter and the cookie

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to design a base controller and do the selected language management there. This way, any controller you derive from the base controller will have access to the feature;

Following is a simple implementation of a base controller which would populate ActiveLanguage, based on a cookie.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string ActiveLanguage { get; set; } 

    public BaseController()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request != null && HttpContext.Request.Cookies != null)
        {
            // copy value from the correct cookie to variable
            var languageCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("name_of_the_cookie");

            ActiveLanguage = languageCookie != null ? languageCookie.Value : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Now any controller derived from BaseController will have a property **ActiveLanguage** on it, which will describe the selected language